# Custom email templates adding variants shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

trying add the size and and color to order confimration email template cant seem to figure it out. Looking at this link https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/notifications/email-variables but there is nothing regarding variants there is there a way to add it ive see on other sites but not sure how they add it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get to the variant information, you need to dig a little deeper than is immediately obvious on Shopify's help page, but you can get there!

If you note the entry on Line Items, you'll notice that there are fields specified like `line.variant.barcode` - this is because the `line.variant` gives you the variant object, and `barcode` is one of those things that variants can have.

In your email template, you could store your variant with a quick `{% assign variant = line.variant %}`, then access any and all properties associated with said variant.

In the theme section of Shopify's help centre, there's more details about the properties of the line_item objects. As far as I know, the line_items used in the email templates are the same line_items used elsewhere. https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/line_item

In that page, you'll see further support for getting the variant object this way:

> line_item.variant 
>   Returns the variant of the line item.

Hope this helps!